# "I took five days off FROM work" vs. "I took five days off OF work"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> I took five days off **from** work last year.
>
> I took five days off **of** work last year.

Which is more appropriate?

Thank you.

Comment: The most natural sentence would just drop the preposition altogether: *I took five days off work last year.*

Answer (score 2):

What is most natural/expected depends on dialect or register. ***From*** is the most formal, in my experience, while which of the two casual versions - ***of*** or nothing - is more natural or normal depends on dialect.

Formal:

> I took five days **off from work** last year.

Informal, dependent on dialect:

> I took five days **off of work** last year.
>   I took five days **off work** last year.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use the word "work" in your sentense, as "5 days off" are explicitly related to work.

So, I would say it depend on the meaning:

- If you want to say that last year, you only took 5 days off :

> I took five days off last year.

- If you want to say that you want more days off this year because you didn't took enough last year:

> I took five days off **remaining from** last year.